# Weight limit of IKEA Lagkapten/Alex desk

Tags: weight-capacity

Not sure if this the best place to ask but worth a shot. I want to put a fish tank on the end of this desk. It is a 10 gallon tank and all up will probably weigh about 65kg (water, substrate, tank included).

Any ideas on the weight limit of this desk and if it will support this tank? IKEA does not list any.

The tank is 50cm x 25cm and will be only over the top of the drawers as they are 60cm x 35cm

[image]

https://www.ikea.com/ca/en/p/lagkapten-alex-desk-black-brown-black-s69417690/

https://www.ikea.com/ca/en/p/alex-drawer-unit-black-brown-60473548/

Comment: Welcome to WW.SE. Unfortunately, this question is off-topic for this SE. Ikea often publish recommendations for some items, but at the end of the day you are going to have to make your best guess. Think about static and racking forces. Can you stand on this desk and feel safe? Maybe it's safe for a tank. But we can't answer this.

Comment: Search the Q&A for "tank" for all the other similarly closed questions.

Comment: Hi Zac, is an Ikea nearby that you can visit? If this desk is on display you can sit on end to test! I think this will be ok, because weight will press down into cabinet, which can take much weight.

Comment: @jdv I find similar questions that are not locked?

Comment: @VolframK I already own it so I suppose I can just do that as is!

Comment: *"I already own it"* Ah that's perfect, you can easily assess whether you think it'll take the weight required using your body weight. Is it safe to assume you are more than 65kg? :-)

Comment: @Graphus Actually I am 65.2kg so cutting it close!

Comment: And thanks @jdv I missed your comment earlier about racking

Comment: *"Actually I am 65.2kg so cutting it close!"* Hehe! I think the last time I was approximately 65kg was around 1979 ROFL

Comment: I am currently using 20 gallon tank on side next to my gaming PC and no problems what so ever. Water level is also right no tilts. Just make sure to use something under the tank like some sort of yoga mat of insulating mat.

Comment: @Graphus 10 months on and both the fish and desk are doing great!

Comment: Good to hear, thanks for the update! Edit: now maybe one or two other helpful souls will finally agree that my Answer was in fact helpful \*sigh*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should be fine, but as mentioned in the Comments you'll want to assess for yourself.

While the knockdown fasteners that Ikea use here are not noted for being a super-strong way to put things together they aren't weak either, and the bolts or cams would have to literally tear out from the chipboard/particleboard for this to fail.

In terms of resistance to racking (any leaning side to side or back to front) back-and-forth motion is a non-issue. Side-to-side motion is a potential for concern however, but the top links the two units quite securely; so IMO both would really have to fail in order for this to collapse sideways.

I just don't see that happening under a *static* load.

But you must plan for unexpected *dynamic* loads, which could include just someone hitting the edge of the desk with their hip as they walk past.

**Note:** if you decide to go ahead, do ensure that all fasteners are tight before you fill the tank with water. Don't over-tighten, but make sure nothing is loose before putting this under load.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I was just discussing with my father and the first thing he mentioned was racking as well. It is in the corner of a room so going to put some 2x4's in the gap to push the load onto the wall if it is bumped. Thankfully I am the only occupant of the room so should be minimal risk of bumping it

Comment: Absolutely perfect then, this removes all potential for collapse I think. Incidentally, similar solution to the one I advised in another Ikea-related Q, [here](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/12663/how-to-i-stop-ikea-s%c3%84ljan-adils-desk-from-wobbling/12676#12676).